# How to call a linked list from a class to another class?

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem and it is by calling a linked list from another linked list. I don't know how to call in the CustomerPark class and putting the element in the textfield.

This is my first class

```
package assignment_parking_2;

import java.util.*;

public class Parking{
public static void main(String[]args){
    LinkedList<String> customers = new LinkedList<String>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int choice=0; 
    do{
        //for(int i=0; i<=25; i++){
       System.out.println("\nRentable Parking Space"); 
       System.out.println("[1]Park a Car"); 
       System.out.println("[2]Leave"); 
       System.out.println("[3]View Parking Lot"); 
       System.out.println("[4]Exit"); 

       System.out.println("Enter choice"); 
       choice = scan.nextInt(); 
       switch(choice){ 
          case 1: 
             System.out.println("Insert your plate number: "); 
             String platenos = scan.next(); 
             customers.addLast(platenos); 
             break;
          case 2: 
             System.out.println("Your customer who has a plate number " +customers.removeFirst()+ " has already left!");
        break;
          case 3: 
             System.out.println("There are " +customers.size()+ " customer/s in the line.");
             CustomerPark viewPark = new CustomerPark();
             viewPark.main(args);
                 int index = 0;
                 while(index<customers.size()){
                 System.out.print("||" + customers.get(index));
                     index+=1;
             }
             break;
          case 4: 
              System.out.println("Thank you for using the System. The system will now exit.");
              break;
           default: 
              System.out.println("You have made an invalid choice, please choose again.");
        }
    // }System.out.println("Sorry the parking space is already full!");
    }
     while(choice!=4);
```

}
}

And my second class

```
package assignment_parking_2;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
```

public class CustomerPark extends JFrame {

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;
private JTextField textField_4;
private JTextField textField_5;
private JTextField textField_6;
private JTextField textField_7;
private JTextField textField_8;
private JTextField textField_9;
private JTextField textField_10;
private JTextField textField_11;
private JTextField textField_12;
private JTextField textField_13;
private JTextField textField_14;
private JTextField textField_15;
private JTextField textField_16;
private JTextField textField_17;
private JTextField textField_18;
private JTextField textField_19;
private JTextField textField_20;
private JTextField textField_21;
private JTextField textField_22;
private JTextField textField_23;
private JTextField textField_24;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                CustomerPark frame = new CustomerPark();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public CustomerPark() {
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("View Parking Lot");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 358, 360);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);


    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setEditable(false);
    textField.setBounds(21, 11, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setEditable(false);
    textField_1.setBounds(83, 11, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setEditable(false);
    textField_2.setBounds(145, 11, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setEditable(false);
    textField_3.setBounds(207, 11, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_3);
    textField_3.setColumns(10);

    textField_4 = new JTextField();
    textField_4.setEditable(false);
    textField_4.setBounds(268, 11, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_4);
    textField_4.setColumns(10);

    textField_5 = new JTextField();
    textField_5.setEditable(false);
    textField_5.setBounds(21, 72, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_5);
    textField_5.setColumns(10);

    textField_6 = new JTextField();
    textField_6.setEditable(false);
    textField_6.setBounds(83, 72, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_6);
    textField_6.setColumns(10);

    textField_7 = new JTextField();
    textField_7.setEditable(false);
    textField_7.setBounds(145, 72, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_7);
    textField_7.setColumns(10);

    textField_8 = new JTextField();
    textField_8.setEditable(false);
    textField_8.setBounds(207, 72, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_8);
    textField_8.setColumns(10);

    textField_9 = new JTextField();
    textField_9.setEditable(false);
    textField_9.setBounds(268, 72, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_9);
    textField_9.setColumns(10);

    textField_10 = new JTextField();
    textField_10.setEditable(false);
    textField_10.setBounds(21, 133, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_10);
    textField_10.setColumns(10);

    textField_11 = new JTextField();
    textField_11.setEditable(false);
    textField_11.setBounds(83, 133, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_11);
    textField_11.setColumns(10);

    textField_12 = new JTextField();
    textField_12.setEditable(false);
    textField_12.setBounds(145, 133, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_12);
    textField_12.setColumns(10);

    textField_13 = new JTextField();
    textField_13.setEditable(false);
    textField_13.setBounds(207, 133, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_13);
    textField_13.setColumns(10);

    textField_14 = new JTextField();
    textField_14.setEditable(false);
    textField_14.setBounds(268, 133, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_14);
    textField_14.setColumns(10);

    textField_15 = new JTextField();
    textField_15.setEditable(false);
    textField_15.setBounds(21, 194, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_15);
    textField_15.setColumns(10);

    textField_16 = new JTextField();
    textField_16.setEditable(false);
    textField_16.setBounds(83, 194, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_16);
    textField_16.setColumns(10);

    textField_17 = new JTextField();
    textField_17.setEditable(false);
    textField_17.setBounds(145, 194, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_17);
    textField_17.setColumns(10);

    textField_18 = new JTextField();
    textField_18.setEditable(false);
    textField_18.setBounds(207, 194, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_18);
    textField_18.setColumns(10);

    textField_19 = new JTextField();
    textField_19.setEditable(false);
    textField_19.setBounds(268, 194, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_19);
    textField_19.setColumns(10);

    textField_20 = new JTextField();
    textField_20.setEditable(false);
    textField_20.setBounds(21, 255, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_20);
    textField_20.setColumns(10);

    textField_21 = new JTextField();
    textField_21.setEditable(false);
    textField_21.setBounds(83, 255, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_21);
    textField_21.setColumns(10);

    textField_22 = new JTextField();
    textField_22.setEditable(false);
    textField_22.setBounds(145, 255, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_22);
    textField_22.setColumns(10);

    textField_23 = new JTextField();
    textField_23.setEditable(false);
    textField_23.setBounds(207, 255, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_23);
    textField_23.setColumns(10);

    textField_24 = new JTextField();
    textField_24.setEditable(false);
    textField_24.setBounds(268, 255, 52, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField_24);
    textField_24.setColumns(10);



}
```

}

I hope you could help me. Thank you!!

Comment: For the love of God, use arrays or ArrayLists and for loops. There's no need for 90% of that code, and if you shrink it appropriately, it will be much easier for all of us to read.

Comment: It almost looks like you're trying to create your own JTable with a collection of JTextFields -- if so, why not use the real thing?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you're trying to shove together a single static main method program with a Swing GUI, and that simply won't work as it's the programming equivalent of mixing oil and water. Re-write your top class as an OOP-compliant class, one with non-static private fields, with public non-static methods (e.g., with "state" and "behavior") and use that as the brains or "model" of your GUI (the "view"). The main method should be short, should suffice only to create and hook up the model with the view and that's it.

So this also means that you'll want to not get user input using a Scanner and System.in but instead create code that gets the user's input via a GUI, since linear console/Scanner code also does not work well with event-driven GUI code.

Other issues -- yes, get rid of all the unnecessary redundancy as it will make maintaining, debugging, and enhancing this program an utter nightmare.

Note that you pass information from one class to another via method and constructors. For instance, if you gave your CustomerPark constructor a LinkedList parameter, you can pass that information into the class on creation.

For example, you could use a 2D array of JTextFields and fill them in the constructor that receives the LinkedList.

```
public CustomerPark(List<String> customerList) {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS, GAP, GAP));
    for (int r = 0; r < textFields.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < textFields[r].length; c++) {
            textFields[r][c] = new JTextField(TF_COLS);
            textFields[r][c].setEditable(false);
            textFields[r][c].setFont(TF_FONT);
            textFields[r][c].setText(customerList.remove(0));
            add(textFields[r][c]);
        }
    }
}
```